# Android Room FOREIGN KEY constraint failed when delete room table

Tags: android, android-room

Im trying to delete all items in RoomDatabase program crash and throw this exception.

DAO

```
  @Query("DELETE FROM Room")
    public void deleteAll();
```

Message

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Room.class,
        parentColumns = "roomId",
        childColumns = "room_id"))
public class Message implements Parcelable {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    private String messageId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "room_id")
    private String room;
    private String message;
    private String userToConnect;
    private String userFullName;
    private String senderId;
    private String senderPhotoUrl;
    @TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
    private Date creationTimestamp;
    private boolean read = false;
```

Room

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = "lastUpdate")})
public class Room implements ProfilePhotoGenerator, Parcelable {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    public String roomId;
    public String roomName;
    public String photoUrl;
    private String userToConnect;
    private String lastMessage;
    private int unReadCount=0;
```

Do you guys have any idea?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think the reason is Room table is using in Message, you should delete Message table before delete Room or you can try `CASCADE` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ForeignKey.html#CASCADE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After test, I see `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` throw when we try to delete a table which have foreign key is using by another **existed** table.

In your case, `Message` table have foreign key refer to `Room` table (it like `Message` table need `Room` table)

Therefore, to delete `Room` table without error, your can

1) Delete `Message` table first then delete `Room` table (the reason is easy to understand)

2) **Or** Use `CASCADE` . When you use it, after you delete some `id` in `Room` table, it will delete all records in `Message` table which have foreign key refer to this `id`.  So if you delete all `Room` table <=> you delete all `Message` table

```
@Entity( foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Room.class,
         parentColumns = "roomId",
         childColumns = "room_id",
         onDelete = CASCADE  
))
public class Message implements Parcelable {
```